# Cython: string to list of strings

Tags: cython

in pure Python it is easy:

```
in_string = 'abc,def,ghi,jklmnop,, '

out = in_string.lower().rstrip().split(',')  # too slow!!!

out -> ['abc','def','ghi','jklmnop','']
```

In my case this is called several million times and I need to speed it up a little. I am already using Cython but I do not know not to speed up this particular portion of code.
There can be up to 300 substrings. Pure ASCII. Letters, numbers and some other printable characters. There can be no comma "," in a substring. So a comma is the separator.

Edit:
OK, I see that a simple question turns into a big one. So the data comes from files which have a CSV-like format (no ready to run software works on this) and in total can be 100GB in size. The method reads the file line by line, needs to get the substrings and then sends the substrings to a SQlite database (I am already using executemany). The whole is done in multiprocessing manner, so each file is processed by its own process. The whole is already fast, but I want to squeeze out the last bit of performance. Additionally I want to learn more about Cython. So I have picked this (simple) part of Python code and have run it with "cython -a" which produces a big amount of generated code. So I think this is the best part to start optimizing. 
Profiling the code is not that easy because of multiprocessing and cython is being used. 
So once someone answers my question, I could implement this code and make a test run. So even I might not improve the speed of my code I will for sure learn a lot. Unfortunately I am a C noob

Comment: Where is the data coming from? If it is a file, then the obvious solution is to write an extesion module in C.

Comment: You **must** profile the code, even if you have to spend time making a new simplified version of the code to do it.  I've seen enough non-intuitive performance characteristics in Python-Cython integration to know that it's very difficult to predict what's faster without a lot of experience. And even then it's easy to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this in Cython, larger question is if you should.

**Where does the input come from?**

Is it a file? Then other optimisations are possible, e.g. you could map the file into memory.

Is it a database or network connection? In that case your runtime is probably dominated by waiting for disk/network.

**What do you plan to do with the output?**

Does the output have to be a string, or can it be a buffer?

```
"abc,def" -> "abc\0def\0"
buffer1 ------^    ^
buffer2 -----------!
```

You mentioned that string splitting fragment was called millions of times, processing the string is not that slow, what probably kills performance is allocating all the small strings, an array to hold the result, and then collecting the garbage once substrings are no longer user.

If you could give out pointers to existing data instead, you could speed things up a bit.

How often are these substrings used? If split is called millions of times, it seems to suggest that most substrings are discarded (or you'd run out of memory).

For example, consider the problem "split into substrings and return numbers only"

```
filter(str.isdigit, "dfasdf,6785,2,dhs,dfgsd,dsg,dsffg".split(","))
```

If you know in advance that most substrings are not numbers, you'd want to optimise this larger problem as a single block.

**How many substrings are there in a typical input?**

If there are 4, like in your example, it's not worth it. If there are millions, or even thousands, you may get somewhere.

**Is there unicode?**

`.lower()` on an ASCII string is trivial, but not so on unicode. I'd stick to Python if you expect unicode.

Comment: The input string comes from a file. CSV like format. There are up to 300 substrings including empty substrings. The array is then further processed with pure Python.

Comment: Please profile your code, I imagine splitting the string is not the slowest part.